# How can I solve these (partial differential) equations?

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to plot b against a with the following equation
$$
    2 r \sin^2{b} \,  \cos{b} \, \sin(a + b) = \sin(a + 2b) \cdot (\sin^2{a} + r\sin^2{b})
$$
with r at >= 0 and let's say <1000

I would exptect the graph to look like this for various r's :
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epPbC.png)

[Additional information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiuO7.png)

How would I be able to solve this equation?

as found from :

Miedema, S. A. (2014). The delft sand, clay and rock cutting model. IOS Press.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that this equation would have an elementary solution.  Also, it's not a partial differential equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is posted just to show there are solutions, but they don't seem to align with the OP's results.  Perhaps the OP's equation is missing something.

Using Mathematica.  This does not match the required Graph, but has some similarities.

```
sol = FullSimplify@Solve[
    2 r Sin[b]^2 Cos[b] Sin[a + b] == Sin[a + 2 b] (Sin[a]^2 + r Sin[b]^2), b];

Show[Table[Plot[b /. sol[[4]], {a, 3.3, 4.7}],
  {r, {0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2}}],
 Frame -> True, Axes -> None,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris, I think when converted to radials this is the way to go. Unsure why the **a** is shifted with 180 degrees, however this does give the best impression of the graph as provided above.